# Isolated storage in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I am trying to do a check on the isolated storage followed by some command along with it.

What i wanted was to **check for directories name consisting "a*"**
**If the directories exist** it will **check if the diretory named after "a + today date" exist.**

If it **exist** will show up a **pop up message telling it does exist**.

But if **no directories consisting of "a*" is exist** at all it will **show a message of "Does not exist"**.

Below is my code:

- Is **able to check if the directories exist** when there is a **directory of "a*" is created.**
- But it **does not work** **when none of the directories "a*" is created**.
  How should i modify my code?

Code:

```
string[] fileNames;
string selectedFolderName;

private void gameBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //MediaPlayer.Stop();

    string currentDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyy");
    string currentDateName = "a" + currentDate;


    IsolatedStorageFile myStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

        fileNames = myStore.GetDirectoryNames("a*");

        foreach (var name in fileNames)
        {
            if (fileNames.Contains(currentDateName))
            {
                selectedFolderName = currentDateName;
                MessageBox.Show("Your schedule for today");
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/DisplaySchedule.xaml?selectedFolderName=" + selectedFolderName, UriKind.Relative));
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No Schdule for today", "Schedule Reminder", MessageBoxButton.OK);
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is just a simple typo.

```
if (fileNames.Contains(currentDateName))
```

should be

```
if (name.Contains(currentDateName))
```

As for handling when there's no directory "a*", check if `fileNames` is empty.

```
if (fileNames.Length == 0) // no Directory 'a' was found, create it
{
     // create code here
}
```

Comment: But anotehr problem is the code dont work when "a*" directory totally does not exist

Comment: Yes, but you're not handling that in your code at all. See my updated answer.

Comment: Oh. Now i understand what is the reason already. Thanks for ur help